# Entity Framework: best practice to filter data inside multiple "one-to-many" relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

In this scenario:

```
public class Software
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Some properties

    public virtual ICollection<Release> Releases { get; set; }
}

public class Release
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public int Version {get; set;}

    public virtual Software Software {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Report> Reports{get; set;}
}

public class Report
{ 
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // Some properties

    public virtual Release Release {get; set;}
}
```

If I have to filter report by Software.Id and by Release.version it's better use this query:

```
from report in context.Reports
where report.Release.Version == filterVersion && 
      report.Release.Software.Id == filterId
select report
```

Or use this query instead?

```
from software in context.Softwares
where software.Id == filterId
     from release in software.Releases
     where release.Version == filterVersion
          from report in release.Reports
          select report
```

It's better "filter first" on data or use entity framework navigation properties?

Comment: check the sql that EF generates (`context.Database.Log`). I'm pretty sure that EF is clever enough to choose the most effective approach with this quite simple scenario.

Comment: I'm guessing that you mean performance wise? Have you looked at the SQL that EF generates? Have you tried to measure the performance of the two different queries? Your best bet is to actually measure it with different data sets.

Answer (score 1):

Of course for us it's impossible to tell which query performs best. That mainly depends on indexes and numbers of records in each table, both of which have a huge impact on the execution plan.

But I think that in your case the query shape turns out to be identical for both alternatives. For example, both `report.Release.Version` and `release.Reports` will generate an inner join. And the predicates will be generated identically.

#### So it boils down to personal preferences.

I always prefer to structure my queries roughly as ...

- `from` the entity I want in the result
- `where` filters
- `select`

... because it is easy to add/remove predicates later.

So that would be:

```
from report in context.Reports
where report.Release.Version == filterVersion && 
      report.Release.Software.Id == filterId
select report
```

In the alternative ...

```
from software in context.Softwares
where software.Id == filterId
     from release in software.Releases
     where release.Version == filterVersion
          from report in release.Reports
          select report
```

... the predicates are "all over the place" (well, it's not that complex, but you know what I mean).

But the picture changes if you want a projection containing data from all entities:

```
from report in context.Reports
where report.Release.Version == filterVersion && 
      report.Release.Software.Id == filterId
select new
{
    report.Name,
    report.Release.Version,
    report.Release.Software.Id,
    report.Release. ...
}
```

... which, because of all dotted references is slightly less readable than ...

```
from software in context.Softwares
where software.Id == filterId
     from release in software.Releases
     where release.Version == filterVersion
          from report in release.Reports
select new
{
    report.Name,
    release.Version,
    software.Id,
    release. ...
}
```

But again, the SQL query may still be identical.

Comment: Just curious what do you mean by *"the picture changes completely"*? Probably the query verbosity, because the generated SQL is still one and the same?

Comment: Ah yes, I mean the way the desired end result affects the choice of the query shape.